# Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime Cannot be shared

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to share the data factory's integration run time with another data factory, but the sharing option is not there in the adf. Is there any limitation in the number of data factories share a single integration runtime. I'm using Azure Data Factory V2. I have attached the screen for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#known-limitations-of-self-hosted-ir-sharing), it doesn't mention limitation in the number of data factories share a single integration runtime.

As your screenshot shows, it is a Linked Self-Hosted integration runtime not Self-Hosted integration runtime, so it can't be shared.

Please make sure it is a Self-Hosted integration runtime. You can check here.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replay @Steve Zaho. Actually the ADF is connected to GIT, if I select the  dropdown to data factory then it shows me the option to share it.